# Evaluating $E(XY)=E(E(XY\mid X=x))$

Tags: probability, statistics

> $X =$ Number of eggs; $X \sim \operatorname{Poi}(\lambda)$
>
> $Y =$ Number of fertilized eggs; $P($An egg is fertilized$)=p$
>
> Assuming that all eggs act independently, find $E(Y)$ and $E(XY)$.

This question is from notes taken in class. I understand how $E(Y)$ is calculated but am confused about $E(XY)$. The working is below:

$Y\mid X=x \sim \operatorname{Bin}(x,p)$

$E(Y)=E(E(Y\mid X=x))=E(xp)=\lambda p$

$E(XY)=E(E(XY\mid X=x))=pE(x^2)=p(\lambda + \lambda ^2)$

Can someone explain how $E(E(XY\mid X=x))$ is being evaluated?

Comment: $\mathsf E(\mathsf E(XY|X=x))=\mathsf E(x\mathsf E(Y|X=x))=\mathsf E(x\cdot xp)=p\mathsf E(x^2)$.

Comment: If you recall how you figured out $\mathsf E(X)=\lambda$, the computation of $\mathsf E(X^2)$ follows almost the same way. Have a shot yourself or check out [this page](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Variance_of_Poisson_Distribution).

Comment: Yeah I figured it out and removed my comment right before you commented.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname{E}}$The equality $\e(\e(XY\mid X=x)) = \e(XY)$ is wrong. If would be right if it said $\e(\e(XY\mid X)) = \e(X).$

The even $X=x$ means the random variable $X$ has some particular value $x.$ For example, if $x=3$ then it would mean $X=3.$ If is not true that $\e(\e(XY\mid X=3)) = \e(XY).$ Rather, $\e(\e(XY\mid X=3)) = \e(\e(3Y)) = 3\e(Y).$

So you have
$$
\e(XY) = \e(\e(XY\mid X)) = \e(X\e(Y))
$$
i.e. if you're given the value of $X$ then it's a constant that can be pulled out of $\e(XY).$ But in the latter expression, $\e(X\e(Y)),$ the expectation $\e(Y)$ is a constant that can be pulled out, yielding $\e(Y)\e(X).$